# Can I make a Grails web app using db2 jdbc driver not commit?

Tags: grails, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange, journaling

My situation:  I work with a lot of RPG programmers who have created files on the IBM-i in a way that does not create a journal.  I've created a Grails app which uses a db2 jdbc driver to connect to a file and update, insert, etc.  I'm getting an error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2DBException: MYFILE in MYLIB not valid for operation.
  Cause . . . . . :   The reason code is 3 .  Reason codes are:
  ...blah blah blah...
  3 -- MYFILE not journaled, no authority to the journal, or the journal state is *STANDBY.  Files with an RI constraint action of CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT must be journaled to the same journal. 
  ...blah blah blah...
```

I know that I could start journaling the file with STRJRNPF, but I'd rather not keep up with it (no scolding please).  Is there a parameter for the db2 jdbc connection url that I can set to let it know not to try to commit?

Here's my current connection info:

```
dataSource
{
  dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
  pooled = true
  url = "jdbc:db2:*local;naming=system;libraries=LIBS;errors=full"
  driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver"
  username = "user"
  password = "pass"
  dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect.class
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is what I've tried:

```
url = "jdbc:db2:*local;naming=system;libraries=LIBS;errors=full;transaction isolation=none"
```

Comment: I think question [8232611](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232611/sql7008-error-workaround) answers this.

Comment: I tried this and got the same error.  Could it be something to do with Grails using Hibernate perhaps?  Is there a Hibernate property that I would need to change?

Comment: I also tried setting auto commit=false.  Same error.

Comment: Don't know Hibernate or Grails.  If you added `transaction isolation=none` to the connection string it should allow you to update to a non-journaled file.  Alternately, try `UPDATE myfile set x=y WITH NC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this did end up having to do with Grails/Hibernate.  Here is what the datasource ended up looking like:

```
dataSource
{
  dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
  pooled = true
  url = "jdbc:db2:*local;naming=system;libraries=LIBS;errors=full;transaction isolation=none"
  driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver"
  username = "user"
  password = "pass"
  dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect.class
  properties{                      
    defaultTransactionIsolation = 0
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Buck Calabro 's comments and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607717/how-to-specify-default-transaction-isolation-level-in-grails).

Comment: Please accept this answer.  By doing that, people in the future who have this problem will be able to see what worked.

Answer (score -1):

What do you think "keep up with it" entails?  By default, the system will do a lot of journal management for you.  Welcome to IBM i.  ;-)

Comment: In no way was it intended as scolding.  It was an honest question,  trying to elicit what you thought the difficulty might be with managing journals, plus a good natured attempt to suggest that on this platform it may be much less work than you imagine. There was nothing negative intended, and I am sorry if my wording left room to be interpreted any other way, when I meant nothing more than to be friendly.

Comment: So to paraphrase...  Didn't I say I wasn't scolding?  ;-)